# Javascript document.getElementById().value='' field executed but no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-io

I'm trying to make a button to clear an input next to it. So far my code is like this,

```
<input type="file" name="lay4img1" id="lay4img1">
<a href="javascript:;"
   onclick="
     if(document.getElementById('lay4img1').value != '') {
       document.getElementById('lay4img1').value = '';
       alert('clear success');
     } else { 
       alert('failed'); 
     }">
   <input type="button" value="Clear">
</a>
```

When I choose a file and make `lay4img1` have value, and then push the button, the alert `clear success` is executed so `document.getElementById` is also executed, but the field is still not empty? What's wrong from my code?

Other than `<input type="file" name="lay4img1" id="lay4img1">`, I still have other fields so I don't want and can't use `<button type="reset">` for it will clear the whole form, which I consider as not user friendly.

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/LHM9V/

Comment: Me too... which browser are you using?

Comment: yes work for me what is your browser?

Comment: Really?? I use Opera 12.02 on Ubuntu 12.04. Strange, it is not working here. Hmm, I'll try another browser then.

Comment: Its working ... test your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ ..maybe there is a problem on your browser.

Comment: Tested in on Firefox 17.0 and it worked fine. Reading http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=685752, seems like Opera developer consider changing value of input type file using javascript to be a big security hole and thus prevent my code from working. Hmmm, do you guys have any other solution to reset the input type file? I can't use input type reset for it will reset the whole form.

Comment: @TendouKishi - You should add this above information to your question so it is clear what you are really asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a horrible way of binding handlers. Additionally, wrapping a button with an anchor is completely pointless. Consider using JS to add an event listener. This listener removes the old input and replaces it with a new one:

HTML:

```
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Clear">
```

JS:

```
function clickhandler(){
     var input = document.getElementById('lay4img1');

     var replacement = document.createElement('input');
     replacement.type = "file";
     replacement.id = 'lay4img1';
     replacement.name = 'lay4img1';

     if(input.value != '') {
       input.parentElement.replaceChild(replacement, input);
       alert('clear success');
     } else { 
       alert('failed'); 
     }
}
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
if (!button.addEventListener) {
    button.attachEvent("onclick", clickhandler);
}
else {
    button.addEventListener("click", clickhandler, false);
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/LHM9V/1/

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Javascript & web programming. May I know why it is considered a horrible way? Also is it possible to pass value to clickhandler, I mean something like document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener(clickhandler(value));, no?

Comment: `addEventListener` is not supported in IE8-, a far more popular browser than Opera (unfortunately).

Comment: @TendouKishi Your javascript should ideally be separated from your markup. This makes it easier to maintain both the JS and the HTML, and doesn't clutter up your HTML file unnecessarily.

Comment: @TendouKishi Also added a fix for the security problem

Answer (score 1):

if the input fields are sibling like below... you can try this javascript code with `onClick` attribute...

```
<form>
     <input type="file" name="lay4img1" id="lay4img1">
     <button type="button" onClick="this.parentNode.getElementsByName('lay4img1')[0].value=new Array();">Clear</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't use button type="reset" for it will reset the whole form. I need the clear button to clear just the input type="file" and don't want to clear the whole form for it will be annoying for the user to re-input all the things.

Comment: @TendouKishi actually you don't need to post the full form... just tell me, is both input fields are inside the tag... means are they siblings...??